# CPU near 100% but exec sp_who2 doesn't return anything RUNNABLE

Tags: sql-server, cpu

I have seen a Microsoft SQL Server with CPU stuck near 100% (RAM was using 20GB of 32GB). Task Manager showed that the SQL Server process was using the most of the CPU.

The strange thing is `exec sp_who2` doesn't return anything RUNNABLE.
Any ideas please?

In the meantime it is being scheduled to restart. It would be nice to know what caused it, and how to solve it without a restart.

Comment: You are speaking about RUNNABLE, what's about RUNNING? Also nothing were?

Comment: if you can, i would recommend installing sp_whoisactive http://whoisactive.com/ . this will give you much better info on currently running processes

Answer (score 1):

In comments and answer there are few great tips mentioned. I am just going to add my experience of handling CPU issues.

First do not look in task manager , probably not the ideal place to check and we’ll SP_who2 is pretty old. The one that I mostly use is from https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit called SP_BlitzWho which gives you some really good insight on what’s hammering on that CPU.

Another great tool which can help you in such performance troubleshooting is extended events. https://github.com/erikdarlingdata/DarlingData You can use sp_PressureDetctor or SP_HumanEvents to get some interesting facts about why server may be struggling with high CPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you have confirmed it is SQL Server process, get my [ViewSessionsConnections](https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools/blob/master/Sessions%20-%20ViewSessionsConnections.sql) stored procedure, and deploy it (create) to any user database.

Run it:

```
exec ViewSessionsConnections 'running'
```

It will show you which sessions actually running at the moment and burning the CPU.

> But would be nice to know what caused it, and how to solve it without a restart.

If you want to know what happened, say, 20 min ago, 1 hour ago, etc. and what caused it, you would need third party monitoring tool such as Redgate SQL Monitor, Idera SQL Manager, etc., these will record in-flight historical data and you can review it later